# Get id(s) after applying batch operation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert, android-sqlite

I am applying a batch of ContentProviderOperations on my provider:

```
ContentProviderResult[] result = resolver.applyBatch(...)
```

Everything works as expected the data is being inserted into the DB, but if I want to extract the id(s) the last element of the uri which should be the id is always null.

Is this happening because I have set the _id of the table to autoincrement (in other words would it work if I am not autoincrementing the id and fill it with a manually uid from my code).

If not, can anyone tell me whats causing this behavior.

**Update**: This is the String for creating the table:

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WORKFLOWSTATES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Tables.WORKFLOWSTATES + " (" 
        + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + WorkflowStatesColumns.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + "UNIQUE ("+ WorkflowStatesColumns.NAME + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE)";
```

and if i view the table I can see the columns _**id** and **name**, the inserted data that is visible shows that the autoincrement works properly.

**Update 2:** This is how I have build the ContentProviderOperation:

this is my ArrayList with ContentProviderOperations (CollectionUtils is a custom class in order to instantiate the Arraylist):

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> batch = CollectionUtils.newArrayList();
```

and this is the actual operation:

```
batch.add(ContentProviderOperation
    .newInsert(InvoiceContract.addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(WorkflowStates.CONTENT_URI))
    .withValue(WorkflowStates.NAME, task.getWFS()).build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of insertion (and I guess that you insert a row into your database), the `result[i].uri` contains URI of a newly inserted row, where i is the index of the corresponding operation in operations array. Try to print this URI and you'll see if it corresponds to real id.

If one of your operation is UPDATE or DELETE the corresponding result URI will be null, but `result[i].count` will contain the number of updated/deleted rows.

**UPDATE**

I guess the problem is that you have a unique index on NAME. Maybe, you have a row already inserted with the same name?

**UPDATE2**

The problem was that the insert function in the ContentProvider did not return the id correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right im inserting, but the uri just contains the base uri with the table where the data is inserted but after that, where the id should appear I am always getting null returned. But the data is always correctly inserted into the table.

Comment: try the following code: ContentUris.parseId(result[i].uri). It should return the id of a newly inserted row.

Comment: Sadly still the same problem, now I get a parsing exception because the returned value is still null and obviously null can't be parsed to long

Comment: is it possible that the insert of sqlite is not returning the autoincremented id on time and therefore null is always being returned (so it would be a system bug)

Comment: Are you sure that your database table contains _id value autoincremented? Can you post the code for creation database?

Comment: I have deleted the database to build a new, tried it, the result is still null, and furthermore just to be sure I deleted it again removed the unique expression and tried again but I am still getting null

Comment: Maybe you can try to do the same using just insert method? If you can insert and you can extract id without problems then it can be a bug in your phone (becuase I checked in Android sources how it should work).

Comment: I would agree to you, but I have debugged on my mobile as well as with the emulator and both are returning null, really frustrating,... I am thinking about making a query for the data I have just inserted, but this is obviously a very redundant solution

Comment: What version of Android do you use?

Comment: 2.2 / 2.3 haven't tested with an emulator using a higher version do you think this could cause the problem??

Comment: I'm checking sources of 2.3.4 version and I do not see what can cause this type of result. Can you also add to the question the code how you create ContentProviderOperation?

Comment: @Nickolaus It's possible that the error is in your implemented insert method of your content provider. Can you post the code of this method? Null value is returned there, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the last hint, already found the problem, you are right I am not returning the inserted id properly in my ContentProvider insert function.